# Binding of ComboBox with ComboBoxItem tags

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

This is probably a millionth question about binding ComboBox, but I didn't find answer anywhere and I read almost all other questions and answers.

I have a ComboBox with items defined in XAML like this:

```
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="265,12,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="120"
              SelectedItem="{Binding MyValue}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Value1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Value2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Value3"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

I have a viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    private string _myValue;
    public string MyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _myValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _myValue= value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyValue));
        }
    }
```

When I switch page (User Control) and return to this one, ComboBox loses its choice. I debugged this and it hits setter and getter. But it just doesn't remember choice. I would really like to add items this way (through XAML), without using ObservableCollection or List or whatever, because I have only 3 values for my Combobox and they don't ever change. I also tried using type `ComboBoxItem` instead of `string` but it is not working. So how do I bind this so that when I switch pages (User Controls) selected choice stays remembered and selected?

Comment: "So how do I bind this so that when I switch pages (User Controls) selected choice stays remembered" - depends on how you do switching pages

Comment: When you define ComboBoxItems explicitly, set `SelectedValuePath="Content"` and `SelectedValue="{Binding MyValue}"` instead of binding SelectedItem.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you very much, that did it. I would probably still be looking how to do it if you didn't helped me. Could you write this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if "switch page / UC" does not create new instance of MyViewModel (just check if ctor is called)
2. SelectedItem it your case seems to be whole ComboBoxItem not probably "Content" of it. As quick test you could expose in your VM "public string[] MyValues => new[] { "Content1", "Content2", "Content3" }" and ComboBox bind this way ItemsSource="{Binding MyValues}" and remove manually created ComboBoxItems in XAML